# SQL Update Subquery returns more than 1 value -

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to run the following code:

```
UPDATE Personnel 
SET TrID        =   (SELECT tp.personID FROM [*******].dbo.tblPerson tp WHERE tp.PersonnelID = PersonnelId)
```

When i run it i get the error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

However when i run the following

```
SELECT COUNT(tp.personID)
FROM [*******].dbo.tblPerson tp
WHERE tp.PersonnelID = PersonnelId
GROUP BY tp.PersonID
HAVING COUNT(tp.personID) > 1
```

I get 0 results so i am confused as to why i am getting this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this:

```
SELECT PersonnelID, COUNT(*)
FROM [*******].dbo.tblPerson tp
GROUP BY PersonnelID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

To fix your problem, you need to choose one of the values.  One method uses `SELECT TOP 1`.  I would recommend you include an `ORDER BY` as well.

EDIT:

The problem would appear to be your syntax.  When you use correlated subqueries, *always* qualify all column names to avoid errors:

```
UPDATE Personnel 
    SET TrID = (SELECT tp.personID
                FROM [*******].dbo.tblPerson tp
                WHERE tp.PersonnelID = Personnel.PersonnelId
               );
```

You have:

```
                WHERE tp.PersonnelID = PersonnelId
```

The scoping rules of SQL evaluates this as:

```
                WHERE tp.PersonnelID = tp.PersonnelId
```

Every non-`NULL` `PersonnelId` matches -- hence the multiple rows error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The query returns no results, indicating there are no duplicate values.

Comment: Running the update with TOP 1 just sets them all to the same value.

Comment: After doing this, it does infact run however it has been running for over 2 minutes now and it is killing my system resources. Considering this is only over 100k records i would have thought it would finish in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @OwainEsau . . . Sounds like you need an index on `tblPerson(PersonnelID)`.